# Rails 3 has many through query all parent records and only include children that meet conditions

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, eager-loading

I have a relationship where restaurants can have many users through a middle table called actions, and users has many restaurants through actions as well.

I am trying to query all restaurants and only include users that meet certain conditions; the restaurant should be returned regardless if there are no users that meet searched criteria, or if there are no users associated with it at all. My models are as follows.

Restaurant model:

```
has_many :actions
has_many :users, through: :actions
```

actions model:

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :restaurant
```

user model:

```
has_many :actions
has_many :restaurants, through: :actions
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do for this situation is use a left outer join. If you just create the join to find users with as specific attribute like:

```
   Restaurant.joins(:users).where("users.name LIKE 'user_name'")
```

an inner join is implicitly created which will leave out all of the restaurants without users. To include them do something like this:

```
Restaurant.joins(["LEFT OUTER JOIN actions on restaurants.id = actions.user_id", "LEFT OUTER JOIN users on users.id = actions.user_id"]).where("users.name LIKE 'James' OR users.name IS NULL ")
```

Comment: Your answer only solves a portion of my issue. That query is returning restaurants with users that meet the search criteria for users, as well as restaurants without any users. However It is not returning restaurants that have users that do not fit the searching criteria. I need it to return all restaurants, regardless if they have matching users or not, as well as if they have no users; while only including users that meet search criteria. Please let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: If you wang it to return restaurants with users who don't fit the query conditions then why add them? Can you give me a specific example of what you want the query to return?

Comment: I am not sure if I can phrase it any better / different than my original question. "I am trying to query all restaurants and only include users that meet certain conditions; the restaurant should be returned regardless if there are no users that meet searched criteria, or if there are no users associated with it at all."

Comment: your statement "only include users that meet certain conditions; the restaurant should be returned regardless if there are no users that meet searched criteria" is mutually exclusive. Give me an example and say  whatt you want/don't want returned

Comment: Please let me know if this is specific enough. Lets say I want to return all restaurants, and include all users associated with that restaurant that are between the ages of 20 and 30 (age is an attribute on the user's model). As I've stated before, if there are no users who meet that condition associated with a restaurant, said restaurant should still be returned.